# How store From-To value and result in an array

Tags: c#, range, containers

I want to store some items with fields "fromValue", "ToValue" , "Info" in an array and write a routine to search an input "value" between "FromValue" & "ToValue" and return "Info" field. I need fast searchable container.

```
FromValue,ToValue,Info   
10,20,TX   
24,56,NY   
input =34 returns NY
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are your efforts? They are hidden? Because I don't see them

Comment: Why not create a class that contains the three fields as properties and put them in a `List<T>`?  Then you can implement your search algorithm.

Comment: You'll probably end up with some sort of sortable container - like "SortedList"; but this just doesn't have enough information "fast" can mean fast to retrieve inserted data or fast to insert new data into - algorithm vary on that.

Comment: Thanks all friends, in my case fast is fast in search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Class:**

```
public class Information
        {
            public int FromValue { get; set; }
            public int ToValue { get; set; }
            public string Info { get; set; }
        }
```

**Search**:

```
   List<Information> Informations = new List<Information>();
    Information infoObj = new Information();
    infoObj.FromValue = 10;
    infoObj.ToValue = 20;
    infoObj.Info = "TX";
    Informations.Add(infoObj);
    Information infoObj2 = new Information();
    infoObj2.FromValue = 24;
    infoObj2.ToValue = 56;
    infoObj2.Info = "NY";
    Informations.Add(infoObj);
    //passing sample input which lies between fromvalue and tovalue
    int sampleInput = 15;
    var result = Informations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FromValue < sampleInput && sampleInput < x.ToValue);
```

Comment: @MohTarvirdi, what if `FromValue` and `ToValue` are not `int`?

Comment: My case is int, but if values are string the compare code should change also. If some one generalized the solution that works with string FromValue and ToValue and also return value as int, it will be great

Answer (score 1):

ok simple, this class defines your generic range.

```
public class Range<TValue, TInfo>
{
    private readonly IComparer<TValue> comparer;

    public Range(IComparer<TValue> comparer)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer;
    }

    public Range(IComparer<TValue> comparer)
        : this(Comparer<TValue>.Default)
    {
    }

    public TValue From { get; set; }
    public TValue To { get; set; }
    public TInfo Info { get; set; }

    public bool InRange(T value, bool inclusive = true)
    {
        var lowerBound = this.comparer.Compare(value, this.From);
        if (lowerBound < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!inclusive && lowerBound == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var upperBound = this.comparer.Compare(value, this.To);
        if (upperBound > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!inclusive && upperBound == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

So, you can have a sequence of ranges,

```
IEnumerable<Range<int, string>> ranges = ...
```

To find all the info values in range you can do,

```
var rangesInRange = ranges.Where(r => r.InRange(42)).Select(r => r.Info);
```

---

You could make a specialised container to improve this operation.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward.
In the most simple scenario just create a class Item

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FromValue { get; set; }
    public int ToValue { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

With this you can initialize your collection of type `List<T>`

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item() {Id = 1, FromValue = 10, ToValue = 20, Info = "TX"}
    new Item() {Id = 2, FromValue = 24, ToValue = 56, Info = "NY"}
    new Item() {Id = 3, FromValue = 15, ToValue = 34, Info = "FL"}
};
```

And with this you can query it to your hearts content.

```
var itemsFromFlorida = Items.Where(it => it.Info == "FL");
```

Comment: @MohTarvirdi, what if `FromValue` and `ToValue` are not `int`?

Comment: The example with Info == "FL" is simple. But checking, whether a value lies in a range will lead to a lot of repeated code. (See last line of Sajeetharan's answer below to see, how ugly this gets.) An object-oriented solution like Jodrell's below is more approppriate, I think.

Comment: I did not really care about the range problem because the OP stated "I need fast searchable container."

Comment: I care about, the data shouldn't overlapped.